# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral

Tags: c#, .net, azure-web-app-service

My application is running fine on local, after i publish to azure web apps it gives me the error

> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

how do I fix this? I do not even have the objectBuilder2, if its something I have to reference where do I get it?Please help

Comment: Did you anywhere use `Enterprise Lib`?

Comment: It's basically saying, that you have a reference to `Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2` in your project. You can check it, if you edit your project file with notepad.

Comment: Are you using any package lib (nuget) ?

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2 is part of Enterprise Library. [See here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/msp-n-p/ee651008(v=pandp.51))
Do you use this library? If not, try to remove references to it. If you use it, then add appropriate .dll to your installation.

Answer (score 0):

For me `Microsoft.Practices.Unity` references was broken. I've just removed and added it again and worked. Maybe any refereces to `Microsoft.Practices.*` that would be broken can show this error.

Answer (score 0):

This could be in a solution where you use `EnterpriseLibrary` for one project and referencing that project in another. Visual Studio could add referenced `Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common` and `Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data` (for example) but not `Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2` to that top level project. So you have to add that reference to the top level project yourself:

```
Your Solution
    Project A
        Reference to EnterpriseLibrary
            Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common
            Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data
            Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2
    Project B
        Reference to Project A
        Reference to Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2 <-- ADD THIS REFERENCE
```

Answer (score -1):

Place Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.dll in bin folder of your web application, this will work.